# LibGDX - Scaled texture is repeating with Clamp to Edge

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite, scale

I am using the following texture

[image: Texture]

It is being displayed only partially and it gets repeated when I used the following code:

```
                    float scale = (float)( (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)(tex.getWidth()));
                    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
                    h = scale * tex.getHeight();

                    float x = 0.0f;
                    float y = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - h * splashTimer;

                    Sprite s = new Sprite(tex);
                    //s.setOriginCenter();


                    //  s.setScale(scale);
                    //s.setOriginCenter();
                    //  s.setOriginCenter();
                    //s.setSize(s.getWidth() * scale, s.getHeight() * scale);
                    //s.setOriginCenter();
                    s.setScale(0.1f);//1.0f + (1.0f - scale));

                    s.setOrigin(0, 0);
                    s.setPosition(x, y);

                    batch.begin();
                    batch.draw(s,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), scale * s.getHeight());
                //  s.draw(batch);
                    batch.end();
```

It gets chopped and repeated in Android and looks like this:

[image]

Orange isn't even drawn. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this happened because I was using mipmaps. I disabled the use of mipmaps and now it works.